# Is the result of the command 'ss' a snapshot of network usage?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, command, ss

I use command 'ss' to check the situation of network.

It takes many minutes because there are huge tcp connections.

Is the result of the 'ss' command **still a Snapshot of network**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **no**, not really a *snapshot*.

Because it base its work on parsing info from the `proc` virtual filesystem, the content of which varies as you actually visit its directories and files. These files and directories do not actually exist per see, they are generated on the fly by the kernel as you visit them, and this can take some time. **So you cannot take a "snapshot" of `proc`.** The same goes from programs such as `top`: it visit all the `/proc/<PID>/` directories, and it changes all the time.

A couple of things that may help speed this up, giving you more of a "snapshot-like" (yet not a snapshot) result:

As can be seen from its man page, `ss` proceed by first parsing `/proc/net/tcp`, which can take some time. Hence a `--summary` option:

```
   -s, --summary
          Print  summary  statistics.  This  option  does not parse socket
          lists obtaining summary from various sources. It is useful  when
          amount  of  sockets  is  so  huge  that parsing /proc/net/tcp is
          painful.
```

You might also want to use the `-n` "no resolve" option (some others programs such as `tcpdump` or `wireshark` also have such an option, which speeds things up a lot).

```
   -n, --numeric
          Do not try to resolve service names.
```